# Как вывести список процессов ОС в ООП стиле

Tags: c++, ооп, winapi

Здравствуйте для перечисления процессов я использую такую функцию:

```
void ProcessClass::GetProcessList()
{
m_count = 0;

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (Process32First(snapshot, &process))
    {
        do {
        m_count++;
//printf("%d) PID: %d, Base Address: %x, Size: %x, Name: %s, CountThread: %d\n", count, process.th32ProcessID,  process.dwSize, process.dwSize, process.szExeFile, process.cntThreads);
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &process));
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
else
{

}

CloseHandle(snapshot);

return;
}
```

Это функция перебирает данные и выводит их. Как вывод отделить от перебора и выполнять его в программе, а не в классе. Потому что бывают случаи когда нужно использовать консольные приложения, оконные и везде вывод может быть разный, то есть в этом классе подготавливаются данные и передаются, а в программе уже решается, что с этими данными делать

Comment: Ну а почему бы не сохранять инфу о каждом процессе в какой нибудь вектор или список? И уже с этим списком/вектором работать как хочешь. Если я конечно правильно тебя понял.

Comment: Правильно поняли!!! Но можно это сделать не использую STL стандартными переменными, указателями? Я бы мог сделать массив PROCESSENTRY32 динамический туда записать все, передать его в программу и потом освободить, но его размер не известен, можно прогнать цикл в пустую потом создать этот массив и в него начать записывать, но количество процессов к этому времени может измениться. И вообще такой подход правильный, если делать к примеру обновляемый список процессов каждые 5 секунд предположим?

Comment: А почему вы не хотите пользоваться stl? Ведь это будет гораздо удобнее и меньше гемороя будет, чем с массивом. А на счет вашей идеи: Если вы сделаете так как хотите и будите очищать память под массив сразу же после передачи его в осн. программу, то в результате указатель в этой самой программу будет ссылаться на не существующую память.

Comment: Я бы сделал так: создал бы список list<PROCESSENTRY32>, создал бы приватную функцию которая будет очищать список и заново заполнять его свежими процессами, и написал мы какой нибудь метод типо const list& GetProcesses() и в ней бы тот самый метод обновления. тогда ваша программа при обращении к методу GetProcesses() будет иметь самые актуальные процессы и никакого гемороя с памятью и тд. Ну или метод обновления можно сделать публичный и вызывать его просто при надобности, чтобы ваш список внутри ос.программы был актуален.

Comment: Гораздо удобнее писать на C# если уж про удобство речь зашла. Почему все используют char* а не string? Мне вот не нравится навороченными вещами пользоваться, PROCESSENTRY32 использую только потому что это winapi, то есть я использую с++ для работы c ОС, а STL boost библиотеки - это не мое, хотя сам собрался использовать stb_truetype =)
Я не знаю, как мне быть. Возможно аллокатор нужен для изменения размера массива PROCESSENTRY32, если его нельзя удалять

Comment: @WenSiL уж очень хорош ваш метод, скорее всего придется его взять((
Если хотите, ответьте на эту тему, я поставлю вам правильный ответ

Comment: Сейчас тогда оформлю как тответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: создал бы список `list<PROCESSENTRY32>`, создал бы приватный метод `update()`, который будет очищать список и заново заполнять его свежими процессами, и написал бы какой-нибудь метод типо `const list& GetProcesses()` и в ней был бы вызов метода `update()`, тогда ваша программа при обращении к методу `GetProcesses()` будет иметь самые актуальные процессы. Ну или метод `update()` можно сделать публичный и вызывать его просто при надобности, чтобы ваш список внутри осн.программы был актуален.

Comment: а в программе нужно создавать переменную типа list<PROCESSENTRY32>  и инициализировать 
list<PROCESSENTRY32>  listProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
 for(std::list<int>::iterator iter = listProcess.begin(); iter != listProcess.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
Так или как то по другому?
А очищать через clear?

Comment: Очищать через `clear()`, да. Инициализация у вас не совсем правильная. Если вы придерживались моего способа, то метод `GetProcesses()` возвращает **ссылку** на список, следовательно и принимать лучше в ссылку. `list<PROCESSENTRY32> &listProcess = Process.GetProcesses();` а в вашем случае `GetProcesses()` возвращает ссылку, но тк принимающий объект не ссылка, то создается копия списка который вернул `GetProcesses()`

Comment: Плюс этой записи (`list<PROCESSENTRY32> &listProcess = Process.GetProcesses();`) еще в том, что если метод `update()` у вас не приватный, то будет достаточно использовать эту запись только 1 раз, а при надобности обновить данные вызывать только `update()`. По поводу беганья по списку: если вам не удобно использовать иттераторы, то можно вместо списка использовать `vector<PROCESSENTRY32>` в нем есть более привычная операция индексации `[ ]`. Так же можно использовать запись типо `for(auto x : listProcess)` (если не ошибаюсь в записи), этот цикл сам пробежит по всем элементам коллекции.

Comment: list<PROCESSENTRY32> &listProcess насчет этого спасибо!!!
А по всему остальному разобрался, особенно был гемор когда нужно было цикл делать не begin к end, а наоборот - я тогда много нового узнал =)
Теперь буду впредь при использовании listView использовать list, благодаря вам. Хорошо это или плохо увидим, надеюсь хорошо =)

Comment: Так же советую ознакомиться [с этим справочником](http://ru.cppreference.com/), возможно что-то еще полезное найдете для вашей программы.

Comment: мои глаза, о нет =) 
Вот вы используете string или char*?

Comment: Я использую string, с ним гораздо удобнее и приятнее работать чем с C строками. Опять же, доступны такие лакшери плюшки типо операции =, +, +=, перегружены все операции сравнения, не нужно заботится о выходе за границы массива и т.д. Не знаю как вы, а я вижу в этом только плюсы. Хотя на самом деле смотря о чем идет речь. если у меня маленькая, простая, как бревно, программа, где не нужно всех плюшек класса string, то я могу использовать и C строки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46782/discussion-between-wensil-and-helldrg).